# Play vimeo domain restricted videos on mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, vimeo

i have some private vimeo videos with domain restricted for my website, now i need to create a mobile app for the website and integrate these videos. Is it possible with the restricted domain? How do i integrate them with my phonegap app?

Answer (score 1):

In Vimeo's new (currently in beta) API3, PRO members have direct access to their video files. This is the only supported way of implementing Vimeo videos into a mobile devices native player.

You can request access at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Some webviews support embedding Vimeo videos, but I do not know how embed privacy works in that context.

Comment: Any new way to achieve this in react-native smoothly now (in 2020)?